# How to convert javascript array to Mongodb Shell syntax?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In our team we are building an API, where we use Mongodb aggregation pipelines to respond. We build these pipelines rather dynamically, depending on the incoming filters. This makes it a bit hard to debug with for example MongoDB Compass. My idea is therefore to debug the aggregation pipeline in Compass, but importing a pipeline requires the pipeline to be in "MongoDB Shell syntax".

**Can I convert a javascript array (containing an aggregation pipeline) to a string of format "MongoDB Shell syntax"**?

I tried with JSON.stringify, but that obviously does not work. If I could the array as MongoDB Shell syntax, I could paste it here:

[image]

And debug the pipeline step by step :)

**Example** pipeline could be:

```js
function buildPipeline(groupId: string, factoriesToFilter?: string[]) {
    const pipeline = [
        {
            $match: {
                ...(factoriesToFilter && {
                    _id: {
                        $in: factoriesToFilter.map((v) => new ObjectId(v)),
                    },
                }),
                groupId,
                ...(!factoriesToFilter && {
                    status: 'active',
                }),
            },
        }
    ];
}
```

Expected output when called with `buildPipeline('abc')`:

```
[
{
  $match: {
    groupId: 'abc',
    status: 'active'
  }
}  
]
```

Turns out the solution was just to JSON.stringify after all..

Comment: Do you have an example pipeline?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I updated the answer with an example "transformation"

Comment: How do you execute the pipeline?

Comment: `someCollection.aggregate(pipeline)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is to JSON.stringify the pipeline object.

Only reason this was not working, was because I returned the result of JSON.stringify through GrahpQL, and here every `"` character was escaped.

Running the string through `replace(/\\/g, '')` solved that issue, and the pipeline could be imported in MongoDB Compass.

**UPDATE**
My final solution looks like this:

```js
const jsonStringified = JSON.stringify(parent.pipeline);
const pipelineReadyToImportInCompas = jsonStringified.replace(/"/g, `'`);
```

Comment: Ok, actually I was quite surprised when you say the tool generates an aggregation pipeline which can be executed but not copy/pasted into MongoDB Compass